# Mutable and immutable borrow issue with assert_eq

Tags: rust

I'm rewriting some C test code for LEDDriver to Rust.

```
struct LEDDriver<'a> {
    address: &'a mut u32,
}

impl<'a> LEDDriver<'a> {
    fn new(address: &'a mut u32) -> Self {
        let leddriver = LEDDriver { address: address };
        *leddriver.address = 0;
        leddriver
    }
}

fn driver_init_leds_off() {
    let ref mut addr = 0xffffffff;
    let leddriver = LEDDriver::new(addr);

    assert_eq!(0, *addr);
}
```

You can run the example [here](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=b0aecbfb5925ab3222de90d5b2cfa692&version=stable)

The issue is with the assert statement which requires the ref to be immutable, but I pass mut ref to the LEDDriver to clear the addr.

Comment: Put the `assert_eq` above the `leddriver` binding and it will work.

Comment: I see here a contradiction: you pass a reference for the mutable ownership and when try to read it. This is clearly forbidden in Rust. You can't have any references if you already have a mutable one. This is a rule of borrow-checker. However, you can have a work-around by using smart pointers or `Rc`.

Comment: _"The issue is with the assert statement which requires the ref to be immutable, [...]"_ The real issue is that you have attempted to use a mutable reference already passed to the `LEDDriver` instance, thus resulting in two mutable references, which is illegal. I would advise you to have a second read of the book on [references and borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html).

Comment: @ljedrz This will compile but I need to check the value of the reference after the LEDDriver initialization.

Comment: @victor-polevoy Your answer would help but I'd have to use RefCell instead of Rc. The issue is higher RAM usage (target is uC) and the interface changes which are not necessary for the usage.

Comment: Is there anything that speaks against writing `assert_eq!(0, *leddriver.address)`?

Comment: @oli_obk-ker Thanks. Simple and elegant solution that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a minimized example, I'm not sure if it matches your real use case, but you can just use `*leddriver.address` instead of `*addr` to access the data after it has been borrowed (since `leddriver` is the one borrowing it)

---

You can also use `Cell`, which does not incur any memory or runtime overhead, but prevents references to the inner value.

```
use std::cell::Cell;

struct LEDDriver<'a> {
    address: &'a Cell<u32>,
}

impl<'a> LEDDriver<'a> {
    fn new(address: &'a Cell<u32>) -> Self {
        let leddriver = LEDDriver { address: address };
        leddriver.address.set(0);
        leddriver
    }
}

fn driver_init_leds_off() {
    let ref mut addr = Cell::new(0xffffffff);
    let leddriver = LEDDriver::new(addr);

    assert_eq!(0, addr.get());
}
```

If the memory location of `addr` will be passed to hardware or modified from interrupts you should be using `Volatile` though, because otherwise Rust is permitted to assume that multiple `addr.get()` without an `addr.set()` in between will yield the same result, even though hardware or interrupts might have changed it

Comment: `Volatile` -- is that the one from the [`volatile`](https://crates.io/crates/volatile) crate?

Comment: Yea that's the one